# TypeError: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads of URL.createObjectURL no Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, firefox

Tenho uma aplicação web com uma funcionalidade de captura de fotos através da webcam. Essa funcionalidade sempre se comportou muito bem no Chrome e no Mozilla Firefox, porém desde ontem está aparecendo o seguinte erro abaixo no console do Mozilla quando eu clico em "Permitir o acesso à Webcam" e a imagem da câmera simplesmente não é exibida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código Javascript para ativação da câmera e captura da foto está da seguinte forma:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video"),
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    context = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    photo = document.getElementById("photo"),
    vendorUrl = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

function abrirModalFoto() {
    $("#modalFoto").show();

    navigator.getMedia =
        navigator.getUserMedia ||
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    navigator.getMedia(
        {
            video: true,
            audio: false
        },
        function(stream) {
            video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
}

var baseImage = "";
function capturarFoto() {
  $("#btn-cancelar-foto").show();
  $("#btn-capturar-foto").hide();
  $("#btn-salvar-foto").show();
  $("#video").hide();
  context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 500, 400);
  baseImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  photo.setAttribute("src", baseImage);
}
```

**Obs. 1: O fato curioso é que o browser se comporta como se a webcam estivesse ativa (pois a luz fica acesa)**

**Obs.2: No Chrome tudo funciona perfeitamente**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução para o problema em uma discussão sobre a depreciação do `createObjectURL` no fórum do próprio Firefox.

Bastou apenas substituir o trecho `video.src = vendorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);`

por `video.srcObject = stream;`

[Fonte](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1334564)